# Interpolate time series (replace NAs) using growth rate of another time series

Tags: r, time-series, data.table, interpolation, na

Let's say I have a dataset like this:

```
trt <- data.table(group = rep(c("a","b"), each = 5), 
                  val1= c(60,62,NA,NA,71, NA, 21,22,NA,25),
                  val2 = c(1,1,1,NA,2, 1,1,NA,NA,2),
                  reflev = rep(c(1.01, 1.03, 1.061, 1.104,1.159), 2))
trt[ , ref:= round(reflev/shift(reflev), 2), by = group]


> trt
    group val1 val2 reflev  ref
 1:     a   60    1  1.010   NA
 2:     a   62    1  1.030 1.02
 3:     a   NA    1  1.061 1.03
 4:     a   NA   NA  1.104 1.04
 5:     a   71    2  1.159 1.05
 6:     b   NA    1  1.010   NA
 7:     b   21    1  1.030 1.02
 8:     b   22   NA  1.061 1.03
 9:     b   NA   NA  1.104 1.04
10:     b   25    2  1.159 1.05
```

Within each group, I would like to replace NA values in val1, val2, and multiple other similar columns (so ideally, lapply would be involved), by multiplying previous available value (e.g. `shift(val1)` or `lag(val1)`) with a value from the `ref` column. If there are several NAs appearing in a sequence after a non-NA value, all of them should be interpolated, using previously interpolated values as a starting point.

So, here is how I imagine calculations to be done:

```
    group val1          val2         reflev  ref
 1:     a   60            1           1.010   NA
 2:     a   62            1           1.030 1.02
 3:     a   62*1.03       1           1.061 1.03
 4:     a   62*1.03*1.04  1*1.04      1.104 1.04
 5:     a   71            2           1.159 1.05
 6:     b   NA            1           1.010   NA
 7:     b   21            1           1.030 1.02
 8:     b   22           1*1.03       1.061 1.03
 9:     b   22*1.04      1*1.03*1.04  1.104 1.04
10:     b   25            2           1.159 1.05
```

Any ideas? Everything I could think of is very dirty and would involve two loops, one for groups and one for desired column.

Comment: What if `ref` and `val1` are both `NA`? What if `val1[1]` is `NA`?

Comment: In those cases, no interpolation is possible/needed, so those NAs should remain NAs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option:

```
cols <- paste0("val", 1L:2L)
trt[, paste0("prev", cols) := lapply(.SD, nafill, type="locf"), group, .SDcols=cols]

trt[, outval1 := fifelse(is.na(val1), prevval1 * cumprod(ref), val1), .(group, rleid(is.na(val1)))]

trt[, outval2 := fifelse(is.na(val2), prevval2 * cumprod(ref), val2), .(group, rleid(is.na(val2)))]
```

---

edit for multiple `val` columns. Maybe something like this:

```
cols <- paste0("V", 1L:30L)
for (x in cols) {
    trt[, c("prev", "ri") := {
            v <- get(x)
            .(nafill(v, "locf"), rleid(is.na(v)))
        }, group]
    trt[, paste0("out", x) := {
            v <- get(x)
            fifelse(is.na(v), prev * cumprod(ref), v)
        }, .(group, ri)]
}
```

or using `melt` which will be faster:

```
mDT <- melt(trt[, rn := .I], measure.vars=patterns("^V"))
mDT[, pv := nafill(value, "locf"), group]
mDT[, nv := fifelse(is.na(value), pv * cumprod(ref), value),
    .(group, variable, rleid(is.na(value)))]
dcast(mDT, rn + group + reflev + ref ~ variable, value.var="nv")
```

sample data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
nc <- 30L
nr <- 3e3L
trt <- data.table(group = rep(1:(nr/5L), each=5L), 
    reflev = 1+runif(nr)/10,
    as.data.table(matrix(sample(c(NA,10,20,30), nc*nr, TRUE), ncol=nc)))
trt[ , ref:= round(reflev/shift(reflev), 2), by = group]
```

Comment: Thanks, understood, very neat solution! Any ideas how the above could be generalized to multiple columns in cols? I have trouble because of val1/val2 in group by.... Have tried something in this direction `trt[, (paste0("out", cols)) := lapply(.SD, function(x)fifelse(is.na(x), prevval1 * cumprod(ref), x)), .(group, rleid(is.na(val1))), .SDcols = cols]`

Comment: Hi how big is your dataset? And how many val columns do you have?

Comment: It's not really big (2000-3000 rows), but has 30 columns

Comment: @Djpengo i added 2 approaches for that

Answer (score 0):

Here is my 'quick an dirty' solution. Happy to hear possibilities for improvement:

```
interpolate <- function(data, int.column){

  for(row in 2:nrow(data)){
    if(is.na(data[row,get(int.column)]) & !is.na(data[row-1, get(int.column)])){
      data[[int.column]][row] <- data[row,ref]*data[[int.column]][row-1]
      }
  }
  return(data[ , get(int.column)])
}
```

I use such a weird call to `int.column` (a name of column to be interpolated)  as I didn't manage to call int.column from a proper environment otherwise and always got an error).

Then
`trt[ , val1:= interpolate(.SD,"val1"), by = group]`  for the interpolation of a single column or

```
columns.to.int <- c("val1", "val2")
trt[ , (columns.to.int):= lapply(columns.to.int, function(x)interpolate(.SD,x)), by = group]
```

for multiple.

Is there any better way?